# Python - Close a file if it is opened

Tags: python

I would like to insert the following function into a Python script, concerning a file, and I haven't found how to write it yet:

if the file is opened, close it
if it is already closed, do nothing

Any help will be really much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) are invaluable.

Comment: Does it mean it needs to close file *opened by another process*?

Answer (score 4):

You write this as `f.close()`.

In Python 3.x, [`IOBase.close`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close) says:

> Flush and close this stream. This method has no effect if the file is already closed.

Likewise, in Python 2.x, [`file.close`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.close) says:

> Close the file … Calling close() more than once is allowed.

---

Of course if you read the docs, you'll notice that files (whether 3.x `IOBase` or 2.x `file`) also have a `closed` attribute, so if you really wanted to write what you were asking for explicitly, you could:

```
if not f.closed:
    f.close()
```

But that has no benefit over just calling `f.close()`. Unless you want to make sure that some file-like objects that aren't 100% file-like raise an inscrutable `AttributeError` instead of just working as you'd like, but I doubt you want that.

Answer (score 0):

`f.close()` is the way to close a file. Python details how to use file operations [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) in python 2 and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) in Python3